# I build ASP.NET Core Web API - when I upload it to server, it does not work

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

When I build my ASP.NET Core Web API locally, it runs very well, but when I upload it to the server, it's not working and return an error 500 Internal Server Error.

The server is free for testing (freeasphosting), with the target framework being .NET 6.0, and the target runtime being portable.

I've tried uploading and changing many settings, but it still doesn't run. I would appreciate your help because I'm stuck.

Comment: Check the server logs. Also check [ask]. Nobody can answer this without details.